# Find the type of a MySQL BLOB object in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, blob, phpmailer

I am storing a file in a MySQL BLOB field using PHP. Latter I am trying to send that BLOB data as an attachment in mail.

My question is: how can I get the type of the BLOB object in PHP? That BLOB object can be a PDF or Word file. Without knowing the file type, we can't send the mail.

Please suggest me the solution, thanks .

Comment: Create new column doc_type and save doc type (pdf/ doc) while saving data in blob field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original file type of the data of a BLOB object is not stored in MySQL, thus one cannot know what file type a file is, instantly.

In order to get the file type, you can do certain things:

- In MySQL, create a field with the file type, and when the file data is stored, also store the file type.
- Check the file signature. Most files have the first bytes the same when they are in the same format. For PDF files, the signature is `%PDF`, for Word files the signature consists of these bytes (displayed in hexadecimals): `50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00`. I've found [a table](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) where you can find many file signatures. Notice that checking the signature does not apply to all file formats.
- To make things easier, you can use the [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) functions in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the file signature. That's the first line of the file defining the file type and version.

For PDF it should be %PDF
For MS Office <= 2003: ÐÏ.à¡±.á
For MS Office > 2003: PK...... (As it's a compressed format, it have the same signature as zip files)

Although, an easier way to achieve this should be to store the doc type when saving the file in a new column.